# Classes with <ul> don't work

Tags: html, css

I just started learning html/css and find some things confusing.

Here is my simple web-page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<ul class:"menu">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my css file:

```
 li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: -35px;
   }  

.menu
{
    width:200px; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    color: #880000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px #880000;
    background-color: #F9E497;
    font-size: 11.4pt;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-top: 5px; 
    margin-bottom: 5px;

}
```

I don't understand why my code doesn't accept .menu class.
When I change .menu to ul in my css file everything works great. 
What am I missing ?

Comment: `class:"menu"` - You have a typo.

Comment: type _class="menu"_ not _class:"menu"_

Comment: You are new to css `<ul class:"menu">` should be `<ul class="menu">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `:` instead of `=`

Try:

```
<ul class="menu">
```

Answer (score 2):

welcome to StackOverflow!

It's often confusing to new users, the difference between various selectors.
In addition to what others have posted, I'll post some general tips.

Use `=` when using **attributes**:

```
<ul class="myClass"></ul>
```

Use `:` when using **styles**:

```
<ul style="color: red;"></ul>
```

Also, in CSS, use `:`, similar to styles:

```
myRule {
    myProperty: myValue;
}
```

In addition to inline styles(as I've done with `ul` above), you can use `<style></style>` tags in your html `<head>`:

```
<head>
  <style>
  myRule {
      myProperty: myValue;
  }
  </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class:"menu">
```

Should be

```
<ul class="menu">
```